# Python UDP server socket and struct program code. struct.pack error "argument out of range"

Tags: python, struct, server, udp, client

I am trying to create a server program that checks if client_id matches with the expected_packet_id. If it does then send an acknowledgment packet back to Client, otherwise ignore the packet. However the program should also randomly choose not to send packet and must wait until the client resends the packet and retries the while loop until acknowledgement is properly sent back. I'm running tests so far and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my struct.pack and how to fix the catch error saying "argument out of range".

This is my server code:

```
expected_packet_id = 0
acked_packet_id = -1
pad_len = (4 - length % 4) % 4
data = bytearray(length + pad_len)
ex_data_length = len(data) + 4

while expected_packet_id < repeat:
    try:
        print("Works here")
        packet, client_address = serverSocket.recvfrom(1024)
        pcode, entity, packet_id, data, data_length = struct.unpack(f"!HHI{ex_data_length}sI", packet)
        print("Works here 2")
        print(f"{pcode}, {entity}, {packet_id}, {data}")
        
        # Check
        if data_length != ex_data_length:
            continue
        
        if packet_id == expected_packet_id:
            print("Works here 3")
            message = struct.pack(f"!IHHI", data_length, pcode, entity, acked_packet_id)
            print("Works here 3.5")
            if random.random() > 0.2:
                print("Works here 4")
                acked_packet_id = expected_packet_id
                serverSocket.sendto(message, clientAddress)
                expected_packet_id += 1
        
        else:
            continue

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error has occured: {str(e)}")
        server_exit()
```

I have test prints within the code and when I run the program this is what prints out.

```
Works here
Works here 2
100, 1, 0, b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\'
Works here 3
An error has occured: argument out of range
```

As you can see, it stops after the pack. I have made sure the pack within server and unpack within client have the same format, so I am lost to what is making my unpack or "out of range" or if I am messing up on something else. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I see the problem with `acked_packet_id = -1`. You are telling `struct.pack` to expect an unsigned value.